# How do I add two search words in the search box?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I work on this site drugs.com and i need to add two drugs name in search box and see interaction between them

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Launch the Chrome browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the drugs.com drug interactions page
driver.get("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.html")

search_box = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "livesearch-interaction-basic")))
search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys('aspirin')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

search_box_2 = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "livesearch-interaction-basic")))
search_box_2.clear()
search_box_2.send_keys('Seroquel')
search_box_2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

this is my code but what I get is either  the code keeps working and does not return any results or adding the name of the first drug and the following error appears

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18368/959725157.py in <module>
     17 search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
     18 
---> 19 search_box_2 = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "livesearch-interaction-basic")))
     20 search_box_2.clear()
     21 search_box_2.send_keys('Seroquel')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     93             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94                 break
---> 95         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     96 
     97     def until_not(self, method, message: str = ""):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0044A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x003DC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x002E5358]
    (No symbol) [0x003109A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00310B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x0033E232]
    (No symbol) [0x0032A784]
    (No symbol) [0x0033C922]
    (No symbol) [0x0032A536]
    (No symbol) [0x003082DC]
    (No symbol) [0x003093DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006AAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006EA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006E456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004D51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x003E5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x003E2328]
    (No symbol) [0x003E240B]
    (No symbol) [0x003D4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76E200C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F67B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F67B1E+238]
```

Comment: I think you need to add a space first, otherwise it tries to look for `aspirinSeroquel` as a single drug name, and you get a popup box that says no results were found

Answer (score 0):

You are facing *`TimeoutException`* as initially once you identify the search box using the line of code:

```
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "livesearch-interaction-basic")))
```

next time the *`id`* attribute of the `<input>` changes as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="livesearch-interaction" class="livesearch" name="searchterm" value="aspirin" placeholder="Enter a drug name" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
```

So second time you need to look for the `<input>` element with *id* as `livesearch-interaction` as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#livesearch-interaction-basic"))).send_keys('aspirin' +Keys.RETURN)
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#livesearch-interaction")))
search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys('Seroquel')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: 2drugs]

Comment: `search_box.clear()` I think the intent was to keep "aspirin" in the search field and add _another_ drug name.  But this won't do that.

Comment: @JohnGordon texts within the search box produces auto-suggestions, so you won't be able to adjust both "aspirin" and "Seroquel" in a single go. Needs multiple iterations.