# How to click on the Check Interactions button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, partiallinktext

I'm working on this site drugs.com to see interaction between two drugs . i added two drug name in search box of this site  and i need to click on check interactions box in this site to see interaction between two drugs in another window .

I used several methods to solve this problem, but I could not solve this problem. This is my code that add two drugs in search box:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Launch the Chrome browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the drugs.com drug interactions page

driver.get("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#livesearch-interaction-basic"))).send_keys('aspirin' +Keys.RETURN)
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#livesearch-interaction")))
search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys('Aleve')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a feedback to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510196/7429447) published against your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76510129/7429447)? You seem to be using the code solution from the answer.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium thank you for help me but i can't vote for your answer because he wants me to have 15 reputation so that I can't vote so I'm sorry

Comment: @undetectedSelenium
I have tried it, but there is a problem that it clicks on the check interactions box after adding or entering the name of the first drug and completely ignores adding or entering the name of the second drug (I want to add or enter the name of the two drugs and then press the check box until I go to the interaction check interactions page and Extract some information from it.)

Comment: Did you go through my previous comment/link?

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as *"Check Interactions"* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Check Interactions"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/interactions-check']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Check Interactions')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I have tried it, but there is a problem that it clicks on the check interactions box after adding or entering the name of the first drug and completely ignores adding or entering the name of the second drug (I want to add or enter the name of the two drugs and then press the check box until I go to the interaction check interactions page and Extract some information from it.) @undetected Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that automates that.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__, "--slow", "--ad-block")

class MyTest(BaseCase):
    def test_drug_interactions(self):
        self.open("https://www.drugs.com/drug_interactions.html")
        self.type("input#livesearch-interaction-basic", "Aspirin")
        self.click('a:contains("Aspirin")')
        self.type("input#livesearch-interaction", "Aleve")
        self.click('a:contains("Aleve")')
        self.click('a[href*="/interactions-check.php?drug_list"]')
        self.sleep(5)
```